# Is it possible to draw min / max lines on Chart JS

Tags: charts, frontend, chart.js

I would like to draw vertical lines with Chart.js like those on the linked image : "Less Satisfied" and "Most Satisfied". Is it possible, and if it is how should I proceed ?

Thanks

[Chart example with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lZl8.png)

Comment: I don't think  that is possible with chart.js without a [plugin.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) You should check the [registry.](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=chartjs-plugin-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the [annotations plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/), thanks to Jesper for the tip !